# Stripe Subscription - Update the stripe subscription amount

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment, subscription, dreamfactory

I have created a plan with subscription amount of 15 dollars for a month of duration using subscription API from the backend. When a customer subscribes to it, next monthly invoice for 15 dollars is automatically created. Now, At the backend admin panel, I must provide an option to change the subscription amount dynamically and when changed, all the upcoming invoices of customers should be updated with the new subscription amount. And whoever subscribes must be subscribed with the newly updated amount.

The problem is stripe doesn't allow us to update the subscription amount for the created plans. For every amount change, a new plan can be created but how to switch all the existing customers to the new plan. If the previous subscription end date has not expired, they must not be charged for a plan change. Can anyone provide a solution to solve this issue?

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/changing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

1) by switching the plan to which a customer is subscribed. [read more](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_plan)

2) by changing the quantity of a plan [read more](https://stripe.com/docs/api#subscription_items)

Hope it helps

Comment: I was trying to update the Subscription, good to see we need to update SubscriptionItem instead thanks